# What CLI flags does Quip Desktop app accept?

Tags: app, quip

I'd like to do the following with the Quip Desktop app on Windows. In short, it helps to know the collection of CLI flags and the name of the protocol used by the Quip Desktop app.

1. Start a new window, opening the Home page. (This can be done with `--new` flag).
2. Pass a URL (or some other identifier) through some other flag, so that a new window opens up with this URL.
3. Duplicate the current quip doc that's active in the current window, in a new window.

For #2, I think I may need some protocol prefix if there is no such viable CLI flag.

Many thanks!